# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open connection

Tags: r, csv

I have been working quite some time now on this script and I am still getting the same error. The file selection window **pops up** as it should but when I select the files I want to work with an error stating:

> "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

appears. Any suggestions or ideas?

```
library(reshape)
library(tcltk2)

mergedPLT <- tk_choose.files(caption = "Select all PLT files", multi = TRUE)
mergedPLT = dir(pattern="*.plt");

fullData = NULL

for (i in 1:length(mergedPLT))
{
  currFileName = mergedPLT[i]
  allData <- read.csv(currFileName, header=FALSE, sep=" ")

  # Verify variable locations later
  accelerate <- as.numeric(allData$V1) # V1
  latAcc <- as.numeric(allData$V2)
  accPedal <- as.numeric(allData$V3)
  BrkPedFor <- as.numeric(allData$V4)
  Gear <- as.numeric(allData$V5)
  Heading <- as.numeric(allData$V6)
  HeadingError <- as.numeric(allData$V7)
  HeadDis <- as.numeric(allData$V8)
  HeadTime <- as.numeric(allData$V9)
  LaneNum <- as.numeric(allData$V10)
  LaneOff <- as.numeric(allData$V11)
  RoadOff <- as.numeric(allData$V12)
  StrWPos <- as.numeric(allData$V13)
  TailDis <- as.numeric(allData$V14)
  TailTime <- as.numeric(allData$V15)
  Velocity <- as.numeric(allData$V16)
  LatVelocity <- as.numeric(allData$V17)
  VerVelocity <- as.numeric(allData$V18)
  XPos <- as.numeric(allData$V19)
  YPos <- as.numeric(allData$V20)
  ZPos <- as.numeric(allData$V21)
  Roll <- as.numeric(allData$V22)
  Pitch <- as.numeric(allData$V23)
  Yaw <- as.numeric(allData$V24)
  RPM <- as.numeric(allData$V25)
  SlipFrtR <- as.numeric(allData$V26)
  SlipFrtL <- as.numeric(allData$V27)
  SlipRearR <- as.numeric(allData$V28)
  SlipRearL <- as.numeric(allData$V29)

  mergedData <- data.frame(accelerate,latAcc,accPedal,BrkPedFor,Gear,Heading,HeadingError,HeadDis,HeadTime,LaneNum,LaneOff,RoadOff,StrWPos,TailDis,TailTime,Velocity,LatVelocity,VerVelocity,XPos,YPos,ZPos,Roll,Pitch,Yaw,RPM,SlipFrtR,SlipFrtL,SlipRearR,SlipRearL)

  fullData = rbind(mergedData) # Use cbind to select certain areas
}

write.csv(fullData, file = "SimData.csv")
```

This script simply takes values from a file on .plt format and rewrites them to a .csv file.

Comment: You seem to be completely overwriting the `mergedPLT` object with the results from `dir()` so it doesn't matter what you choose. What are the values in `mergedPLT`. Are they all valid files you have permission to read? Do you get the same error if you take out all the `as.numeric` stuff in the middle?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, they are valid files that I have permission to read. I will try your suggestion and post an update. Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick Thank You! Eliminating dir() fixed the error